# Highcharts - Redundant Y Axis Point Markers (Any insight welcome!)

Tags: jquery, dynamic, charts, highcharts, yaxis

Having an issue with a dynamic multiple Y axes. Occasionally the spline lines register two data points and botch the spline up. 
This code is within programable logic controller that employs a "widget adapter" in which the HTML is handled separately.
I am admittedly a hack at this and have managed to get pretty close to the result I want. However, I have run into this roadblock where these duplicate point markers are mucking up the works.
Any advice is welcome.

[MultiYAxesPointMarker Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23ftQ.jpg)

```
   // define javascript methods that will be called when widget need to be initialized or data updated. 
   // in these methods' context, beside jQuery, following variables are accessible:
   //   * this.elem - parent DOM element 
   //   * this.datas - data object, you can access data by this.datas['data1'], this.datas['data2'] ... this.datas['data16'].
   //                  data may be undefined if it is not binded in CPT

   // [optional] if this method defined, it should return a array of required javascript files
   // below is an example for highcharts:
   //
   this.requiredScripts = function() {   
   return ["../user_codes/highcharts/js/highcharts.js",
       "../user_codes/highcharts/js/highcharts-more.js",
       "../user_codes/highcharts/js/exporting.js"];
   };

    this.init = function() {   
   // PUT INITIALIZATION CODES BELOW         
   Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
       });

   $(this.elem).highcharts({
        chart: {
            //type: 'line',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            duration:250,
            marginRight: 250,
            marginLeft:  125,
            events: {
            }
        },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        title: {
            text: 'Energy Valve'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 100,
        },  
    //yAxisyAxisyAxisyAxisyAxisyAxisyAxisyAxisyAxisyAxisyAxis                

        yAxis: [{//-------------------------------FLOW
            yAxis:0,
            min:0,
            max:10,
            startOnTick:false,
            endOnTick:false,
            title: {
              text: 'Flow',
              style:{
                 color: '#0b8dbc'
              }
            },

            labels: {
              format: '{value}gpm',
              style: {
                color:'#0b8dbc'
              }
            },
            opposite:false
        },{      //-----------------------------------Valve Position  
            yAxis:1,
            min:0,
            max:100,
            startOnTick:false,
            endOnTick:false,
            title: {
            text: 'Valve Position',
            style:{
              color: '#046804'
              }
            },
            labels: {
              format: '{value}%',
              style: {
                color: '#046804'
              }
            },
            opposite:true

        },{     //------------------------------- Diff Pressure
            yAxis:2,
            min:0,
            max:20,
            startOnTick:false,
            endOnTick:false,
            title: {
            text: 'Diff Pressure',
            style:{
              color: 'rgb(255,124,14)'
              }
            },
            labels: {
              format: '{value}psi',
              style: {
                color: 'rgb(255,124,14)'
              }
            },
            opposite:true
        }],

        legend: {
            enabled:true,
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 110,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 37,
            floating: false,
            backgroundColor:  'rgba(252, 249, 237,0.52)'
                },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
   //SeriesSeriesSeriesSeriesSeriesSeriesSeriesSeries            
        series: [{
           //-------------------------------Flow 
            yAxis:0,
            name: 'Flow',
            color:'#0b8dbc',
            type: 'spline',
            lineColor:'#0b8dbc',
            //fillColor:'rgba(174, 222, 239,0.2)',
            marker: {
              fillColor: '#aedeef',
              lineWidth: 1,
              lineColor: '#0878a0' // inherit from series
            },

            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }()),

        },{ 
          //-----------------------------------Valve Position  
            yAxis:1,
            name: 'Valve Position',
            color:'#046804',
            type: 'spline',
            lineColor:'#046804',
            //fillColor:'rgba(174, 222, 239,0.2)',
            marker: {
              fillColor: '#5cd12e',
              lineWidth: 1,
              lineColor: '#046804' // inherit from series
            },
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1)
                    });
                }
                return data;

            }()),


        },{ 
          //------------------------------- Diff Pressure
          yAxis:2,
          name: 'Diff Pressure',
            color:'rgba(255, 124, 14,0.2)',
            type: 'areaspline',
            lineColor:'#ff7c0e',
            fillColor:'rgba(255, 124, 14,0.2)',
            marker: {
              fillColor: '#eda66a',
              lineWidth: 1,
              lineColor: '#bc5905' // inherit from series
            },
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1)
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }
            ()),







        }]
    });
};

this.update = function() {

 //PUT DATA UPDATE CODES BELOW
 var index = $(this.elem).data("highchartsChart");
 var chart = Highcharts.charts[index];
var series0 = chart.series[0];
var series1 = chart.series[1];
 var series2 = chart.series[2];
 var data0 = this.readData("@GPM");
 var data1 = this.readData("@POS");
 var data2 = this.readData("@DP");
 var x = (new Date()).getTime();
 var y = parseFloat(data0);
 var z = parseFloat(data1);
 var c = parseFloat(data2);


series0.addPoint([x,y], true, true);
 series1.addPoint([x,z], true, true);
 series2.addPoint([x,c], true, true);

};

this.cleanup = function() {
//PUT CLEAN UP CODES BELOW
 //JL 1-9-18
};
```

Comment: Maybe they are no duplicate, and instead are real data (peaks pehaps?)

Comment: You're absolutely right.The data behind these points is indeed constantly in flux. Any suggestions you could share to mitigate the frequency of updates?

Comment: Working my previous comment and some suggestions into an answer

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48211848/highcharts-redundant-y-axis-point-markers-any-insight-welcome?noredirect=1#comment83405122_48211848), those data values seem to be regular values instead of duplicate points; they just happen to be really *close events in time*. As per your comment:

> Any suggestions you could share to mitigate the frequency of updates?

Analyzing your code we can see that you plot new points into your chart every time `this.update = function(){}` is called. Your charts presents these really-close points because that function is surely called at a non-fixed interval, so your `x = (new Date()).getTime();` values are really close together if you update frequently.

Of course one way of solving this is to **call your `update` function at regular intervals**, so you don't get values too close to each other in time.

However, if you are not able to do so (I suggest you try, though), an alternative solution would be to **only add points after verifying the time ellapsed between calls to `update`**. You can achieve this by storing your `x` variable elsewhere, to compare it on the next time you call `update`.

You can then check if there has been a *minimum elapsed time* (say 60 seconds) between calls and then decide if you want to plot points or not. This way you will be able to eradicate those "repeated" values in case you can't handle the frequency of the calls to `update`.

**Edit:** To illustrate the second option with an example, what I suggest would look something like the following.

First, you will have to store the initial time in a variable that we can use to track the time of last update:

```
//Somewhere inside your initialization, capture the date you start the program
this.init = function() {
  var previousUpdate = (new Date()).getTime();

  //...the rest of your code...
}
```

After that, you can use that variable on your update call to see if you plot or not, on the lines of:

```
//Now, on your update, we can compare time between calls   
this.update = function() {
 //get the time now
 var x = (new Date()).getTime();

 //now, compare if some minimum time interval has elapsed
 var timeInterval = x - previousUpdate 
 //Remember to update your previous time for next comparison
 previousUpdate = x
 //if time ellapsed is more than, say, 1000 units (depends what units you want)
 //then plot, else don't do anything
 if(timeInterval > 1000){
   //PUT DATA UPDATE CODES BELOW
   var index = $(this.elem).data("highchartsChart");
   var chart = Highcharts.charts[index];
   var series0 = chart.series[0];
   var series1 = chart.series[1];
   var series2 = chart.series[2];
   var data0 = this.readData("@GPM");
   var data1 = this.readData("@POS");
   var data2 = this.readData("@DP");
   var y = parseFloat(data0);
   var z = parseFloat(data1);
   var c = parseFloat(data2);

   series0.addPoint([x,y], true, true);
   series1.addPoint([x,z], true, true);
   series2.addPoint([x,c], true, true);
 }
 //else just do nothing :)
};
```

With this you will only plot points to your chart if they are sufficiently distant from each other in time, and you can then modulate that minimum distance to fit your needs (smaller means allow frequent updates and vice-versa).

Comment: Thank you for directing me to the source of my issue. I've been attempting to utilize setInterval() within the update for some time now in various iterations without much luck, unfortunately. Am I heading down the right road here?

Comment: Hey @JustinLindstrom I think you are indeed on the right way, if you can determine a time interval from the last call to update you can then easily call addPoint only if they are at least (>=) N seconds apart from each other. This way you won't have points too often

Comment: Thanks again. It appears I'm actually making the graphs a little bit worse for wear. Should I call the setInterval() for the entire update or just the series.addPoint? I've attempted both but am getting some errors and console alarms. It might be time to go to sleep. Its been a long day with this.

Comment: @JustinLindstrom yeah, sometimes a good night sleep can do wonders. I think you may be overcomplicating yourself, if you want ping me tomorrow so we can continue

Comment: Got a little sleep :). So I backed out and went over the "adapter widget" documentation and there is a note that states whenever the @userProperty I.e,“@GPM” , “@DP” and “@PSI” in my case, is updated within the controller the this.update callback will execute and post the data into the associated var.

Comment: @JustinLindstrom this means that whenever those properties change you *will* be getting an update. In that case I guess you could read more about that docs to see if you can slow down that frequency. However, another way to achieve that filtering is what suggested earlier (when update is called, check this time and time of last update, and do nothing if it falls under certain time frame you want).

Comment: I began working the issues on the controller side. I removed decimal places on the data, added an averaging filter which did help a bit but there is not a way to time the data "release" so to speak. if there is a big swing in the data. the issue remains.  I'm trying now to isolate the this.readData("@GPM");  as they seem to be the update driver.

Comment: Good luck with that @JustinLindstrom , do inform if you get any results. However, I must insist and say that you may be over-complicating yourself. By simply obtaining the time between update you could easily decide which plots to avoid, without having to do something more complicated like regulating the calls to update. Still you may try the latter, but the solution offered I think will work without complicating things.

Comment: I certainly do not want to overcomplicate it. Not by any means. Could you direct me to a subject topic I could research how to do what you propose (time between update/plot avoidance)?   I am thankful for your guidance. I' m learning quite a bit.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to do that.

Comment: @JustinLindstrom done, hope this time it is clearer what I mean :)

Comment: As the .update works through wouldn't the previousUpdate = x value be posted when the seriesX.addpoint ([x,y]),true,true); be then posted to the chart and not the current time (new Date()).getTime()? I've implemented your suggestions but the chart unfortunately is now stagnant.

Comment: I cracked it. Thanks for pointing me down the right path. Will update post tomorrow for others and yourself. Thanks again.

Comment: @JustinLindstrom great to hear that :) glad I could help